# Remove First 2 Specific Same Char

Tags: c#, winforms

just wondering, Is there a way i can remove first specific 2char every line ?

e.g:
i have this set of string:

```
****wa\n
****we\n
****wi\n
```

and i want to remove first 2(*) everyLine so it will become:

```
**wa\n
**we\n
**wi\n
```

but this linecode will replace all * :

```
text.Replace("*", "");
```

and that will be wrong . only first 2 * .

thanks in advance !

Comment: `text = text.SubString(2);` ?

Comment: `text = text.Remove(0, 2);` ?

Comment: Do you have lines with less than 2 chars? How many lines do you have to process?

Comment: the lines are in a generic list  of string?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
text = text.SubString(2);
```

string's method called `SubString(Int32)`

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

as it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your lines in single string, you can use combination of `string.Split` and `string.Join`:

```
string separator = "\n";
string input = "****wa\n****we\n****wi\n";
var output = string.Join(separator,
                         input.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                              .Select(line => line.Substring(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of string, you can use linq

```
        List<String> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("****wa");
        list.Add("****we");
        list.Add("****wi");
        List<String> shortList = list.Select(x => x.Substring(2)).ToList();
```